# Update badge style in the rep leagues

Tags: feature-request, design, stackexchange.com, reputation-leagues

All standard sites:
[image: pic1]

[User reputation league](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/week/meta), and pretty much all of StackExchange.com (as pointed out by [nicael in the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252275/update-badge-style-in-the-rep-leagues#comment824053_252275)):
[image: pic2]

Please change the badges in the user reputation league to the new, clean UI system.

I just don't see a point in keeping StackExchange badges older looking and lower image quality compared Meta, StackOverflow, etc.

---

**Edit:**

I know this is an incredibly long time since the question was first asked, but this is still the case, so I'm wondering if this is ever going to be changed into the newer system.

Comment: Just between you and me, I like the old look better.

Comment: Oh, if you're taking about the leagues, take the whole http://stackexchange.com :D it is still styled with old beta theme :)